# Using embedded symbols with WinDbg

Tags: .net, windows, windbg, sos, sosex

I've compiled my assemby with embedded symbols:

```csharp
namespace SymbolsTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var now = System.DateTime.Now;
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Now:  {now}");
        }
    }
}
```

```
csc SymbolsTest.cs /target:exe /platform:x64 /debug+ /debug:embedded /out:SymbolsTest_x64.exe
```

When I try to load the symbols in WinDbg, I get an error in the symbol loading:

```
0:000> !CLRStack
OS Thread Id: 0x21e4 (0)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
0000000000dfe940 00007ffa7a0b6004 [PrestubMethodFrame: 0000000000dfe940] SymbolsTest.Program.Main()
0000000000dfee30 00007ffa7a0b6004 [GCFrame: 0000000000dfee30] 
0:000> .reload
Reloading current modules
................................
0:000> .reload /f
Reloading current modules
.*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for SymbolsTest_x64.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for SymbolsTest_x64.exe
...........*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files\Avecto\Privilege Guard Client\PGHook.dll - 
....................

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
SymbolsTest_x64        0x80190194 - Not found (404). : srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
PGHook                 0x80190194 - Not found (404). : srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

You can troubleshoot most symbol related issues by turning on symbol loading diagnostics (!sym noisy) and repeating the command that caused symbols to be loaded.
You should also verify that your symbol search path (.sympath) is correct.
```

The `sympath` is set correctly (*what I think is correct*):

```
0:000> .sympath
Symbol search path is: srv*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Expanded Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

How so I tell the debugger to that the symbols are embedded in the file?

Comment: have you tried :full and does it work  do you get a pdb

Comment: Where did you get the `/debug:embedded` option from? Not documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/debug-compiler-option) at least.

Comment: @thomas  do csc /? and look at help for debug options  there are supposed to be 4 options   including embedded  default is full

Comment: @blabb Aye, if I create the debug file and add it to the symbol server it's fine.

Comment: then ptobably embedded has an issue it appears to be semi / unofficial feature  some rosalyn boards has reference to its usage with sourcelink feature   you may have to look in insider previews

Comment: @blabb maybe that's it, I thought it would be less hassle than constantly adding the symbols locally.

Comment: @BanksySan: usually you'd not embedd symbols. They can grow some MB, which might affect deploy size and affect loading time of DLLs as well as memory used by DLLs (nothing bad for 64 bit, though). Also, for closed source apps you'd not like to ship symbols.

Comment: @ThomasWeller This is just for poking about with the debuggers, I thought that embedded symbols might save me having to add the symbols file to the local symbol store.  I'd never embed them on a _real_ application.